# Where does ext4 store directory sizes?

Tags: directory, ext4

Where does ext4 store directory sizes? Are they stored in the directory inode?

For example, when I run `du -h`, it returns directories' size instantly, so I don't believe it calculates it at that time.

I'm using ext4 on Linux.

Comment: ext4 doesn't store directory sizes. If `du` feels instantaneous it's because the files are cached by the kernel. You can see this if you try to run it multiple times on a recently mounted file system - it'll be much faster after the first run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `strace` would seem to indicate that the file sizes are indeed calculated by querying the files within the directory.

#### Example

Say I fill a directory with 3 1MB files.

```
$ mkdir adir
$ fallocate -l 1M adir/afile1.txt
$ fallocate -l 1M adir/afile2.txt
$ fallocate -l 1M adir/afile3.txt
```

Now when we trace the `du -h` command:

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o du.log du -h adir/
3.1M    adir/
```

Looking at the resulting `strace` log file `du.log`:

```
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "adir/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)     = 144
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(4, "afile2.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1048576, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(4, "afile3.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1048576, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(4, "afile1.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1048576, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x231a000
...
```

Notice the `newfstatat` system calls? These are getting the size of each file in turn.

#### Additional Background

If you're interested here's a bit more on the subject.

1. This behavior has nothing to do with EXT4. This is just how filesystems work in Unix.
2. The `stat` command provides no facility for querying anything other then the size of a filesystem object (directory or file).

   ```
   $ stat adir/
     File: ‘adir/’
     Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
   Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 11539929    Links: 2
   Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    saml)   Gid: ( 1000/    saml)
   Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
   Access: 2014-04-15 22:29:25.289639888 -0400
   Modify: 2014-04-15 22:29:44.977638542 -0400
   Change: 2014-04-15 22:29:44.977638542 -0400
    Birth: -
   ```

   Notice it's 4096 bytes. That's the actual size of the directory itself, not what it contains.

#### References

- [Some new system calls](http://lwn.net/Articles/164887/)

Comment: I'd add that this isn't just ext4; `stat` simply doesn't have a way to return multiple sizes—so it can only return the size of the directory *itself*, not of its contents. And also "directory size including contents" becomes less clear when you have hardlinked files.